# Get multiple barcode strings from Google Vision

Tags: android, google-vision

I'm using Google vision for a week now. but the problem is, when it sees multiple barcodes, it randomly chooses any barcodes & returns only one string. I'm trying to get all the barcodes it sees.

[Barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56kgo.jpg)

In the picture above, there are multiple Barcodes. Right now, for one barcode, I'm doing this in BarcodeCaptureActivity:

```
@Override
    public void onBarcodeDetected(Barcode barcode) {
        //do something with barcode data returned

        Log.d(TAG, "...::: BARCODE :::...");
        Log.d(TAG, "" + barcode.rawValue);
        Log.d(TAG, "...::: BARCODE :::...");

    }
```

I'm trying to make it return an array of string with all the barcodes. But how to do it?

Comment: The best solution is, use OpenCV to find all the barcode and split them into 2 images, then use google vision to recognize them @gabikefiv

Comment: Good idea. Thanks :)